# Populate 'temporary' columns with corresponding values during MySQL join query, also limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm doing several MySQL joins to get template variables (i.e. custom fields) and their values (in MODX Evo but it's irrelevant - this is a general MySQL query).

I'm looking ideally to be able to create 2 temporary columns in order to use SORT BY in the query, or something to this effect. I'd like to populate the values for 'event_date' and 'event_featured' for their corresponding id's in these new columns - then I could then sort the results by these columns.

On a very related note I would like to limit the results to 20 for each unique id, not for each row as would happen if I added LIMIT- it would crop the below result to the . Can this be accomplished at the same time?

Anybody know how / if these are possible? Many thanks in advance.

Code and image of the results below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    content.id, content.pagetitle, content.template , content.published,
    templates.templatename,
    tv_props.name,
    tv_values.value

FROM `modx_site_content` AS `content`
LEFT JOIN `modx_site_templates` AS `templates` ON content.template=templates.id
LEFT JOIN `modx_site_tmplvar_templates` AS `template_tvs` ON templates.id=template_tvs.templateid
LEFT JOIN `modx_site_tmplvars` AS `tv_props` ON template_tvs.tmplvarid=tv_props.id
LEFT JOIN `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` AS `tv_values` ON template_tvs.tmplvarid=tv_values.tmplvarid

WHERE templates.id=89
AND (
    tv_props.name='event_featured'
OR tv_props.name='event_link_through'
OR tv_props.name='event_title'
OR tv_props.name='event_date'
OR tv_props.name='event_date_text'
OR tv_props.name='event_short_description'
OR tv_props.name='event_list_image'
);
```

[Link to full-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XImZI.png)
[image: Query result]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify, if you can, what you want to see in each row of the result you want. What do you mean by "unique id" -- is that content.id?

Comment: Hi Ollie. Sorry yes, content.id. Basically I'm looking to get 2 extra temporary columns - event_date and event_featured... the values for each will be the same for all those with the same content.id. The values for the column are taken from the tv_values.value that corresponds to the tv_props.name row but for all with that content.id - does that make sense?
Thanks :)

Comment: It does make sense. Thanks for the clarification. Please consider editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a couple of virtual tables, also known as subqueries, to retrieve these two properties of events from your name/value table. The generic name for this kind of query is a "pivot," for your information.

The mental knack is to think of the subquery as a virtual table which you can use in a surrounding query.  The subquery for event_date looks like this, I believe.

```
      SELECT content.id        AS id,
     tv_values.value   AS event_date
        FROM modx_site_content               AS content
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_templates             AS templates 
      ON content.template=templates.id
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_templates     AS template_tvs 
      ON templates.id=template_tvs.templateid
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvars              AS tv_props 
      ON template_tvs.tmplvarid=tv_props.id
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS tv_values 
      ON template_tvs.tmplvarid=tv_values.tmplvarid
       WHERE tv_props.name = 'event_date'
```

This little query produces a resultset that's a table relating content id to event date.   I honestly don't understand your schema well enough to know if there's just one event date for each content id, so you might need to adjust this query to SELECT more columns.   As you debug this, you should try out the subquery and  make sure it's giving the results you hope for.

Then, when you're sure the subquery is OK, you join that subquery into your overall query, generically like so.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
          content.id, event_date.event_date, templates.column,
          table.column, table.colum, etc, etc
     FROM modx_site_content AS content
    LEFT JOIN table ON condition
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT content.id        AS id,
     tv_values.value   AS event_date
        FROM modx_site_content               AS content
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_templates             AS templates 
      ON content.template=templates.id
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_templates     AS template_tvs 
      ON templates.id=template_tvs.templateid
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvars              AS tv_props 
      ON template_tvs.tmplvarid=tv_props.id
   LEFT JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS tv_values 
      ON template_tvs.tmplvarid=tv_values.tmplvarid
       WHERE tv_props.name = 'event_date'
     ) AS event_date ON event_date.id = content.id
LEFT JOIN etc, etc, etc.
    WHERE etc etc etc
```

Do you see how that goes? You can use `tablename AS table` or `(some query) AS table` interchangeably. You can also define a `VIEW` in your schema that provides the same data, and name it in your query.  That's a handy way to make your queries less hairy.

By the way, you'll boost performance if you change

```
AND (
    tv_props.name='event_featured'
 OR tv_props.name='event_link_through'
 OR tv_props.name='event_title' etc  )
```

to

```
 AND tv.props.name IN ('event_featured',
                       'event_link_through',
                       'event_title', etc)
```

You've probably noticed I'm a bit of a stickler for indentation in SQL queries.  I find this helpful; I often find mistakes while I'm fixing up the indentation.  Your practice may vary.

Comment: That's amazing Ollie, thank you - you seem like a gifted tutor. I had no idea about pivot tables, you've just broadened my very limited MySQL knowledge massively :) . Because of the overhead my queries were generating I've been forced  to change course whist taking on board what you've said so far. Instead of selecting everything at once it'll be a 2-query approach - the first of which has left me with another issue detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356887/implementing-a-where-clause-within-a-subquery-for-the-value-of-a-pivot-column
Thanks again :)